# Are any of these expressions inherently condescending

Tags: phrase-usage

I know it depends on the context but I want to get a general idea of whether the following expressions are inherently/likely condescending, in most cases, when used before or after answering a question.

- Do you think it's right that ...
- Does it make sense (to you)?
- Did I answer your question?
- Have I made myself clear?

Comment: None is inherently condescending; all might be condescending--or threatening, or peevish, or humble, or anxious ...

Comment: I agree with @StoneyB. Some expressions can sound sincere or condescending; the tone in which they are uttered carry more weight than the words themselves. You've done a great job listing four such questions. I could envision a teacher asking these questions, wanting to be sure the students are understanding the lesson. I can also imagine some smart aleck saying the very same words, but with a much different tone and intent.

Comment: I think that "**Have I made myself clear?**" is a troublesome way of putting it. It's usually used to confirm an order or a reprimand or an unpleasant decision. I'd suggest changing it to "**Was my answer clear and unambiguous?**"

Comment: I have updated the question to make it more specific. I think @StoneyB 's comment is mostly the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @Bill: I agree with that, too. A teacher would probably say, "Is that clear?" instead of, "Have I made myself clear?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that the person stating this isn't intending to be sarcastic, the first one offers an opportunity to paraphrase what was asked and thus is probably not that likely to be condescending.

The "Does it make sense?" may be shortened to "Make sense?" where someone may be confused though it is possible that this could have tones of arrogance or sarcasm that could make it condescending.

"Did I answer your question?" gets a bit closer to being condescending as this implies a miscommunication.

"Have I made myself clear?" is the closest to being condescending since there is an emphasis on the speaker and thus could be where someone is being scolded or reprimanded.